# Rails Validate child with parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, forms, activerecord, nested-forms

I have a nested Form

A Crew can have many meetings, a Meeting can belong to one Crew.
A Crew, and a Meeting can both have set a gender_id attribute.

I want to add an error to the Meeting object when Crew.meeting_id != Meeting.gender_id

I have written a simple validator

```
class MeetingGenderValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if record.gender_id != record.crew.gender_id
      msg = :wrong_gender
      case record.crew.gender_id
        when 1 then
          msg = :crew_woman_only
        when 2 then
          msg = :crew_man_only
        record.errors.add(attribute, msg, options)
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

The problem is, When this validator is run, The record variable (our Meeting model), is not yet associated with the Crew model, so I get an error on calling Nil.gender_id

Here is the part of Meeting model:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :crew 
  validates :gender_id, :meeting_gender => true
end
```

Here is the part of Crew model with the association:

```
class Crew < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :meetings
end
```

And my Crews#Create action snippet (controller):

```
class CrewsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @crew = Crew.new(params[:crew]) # here are the meeting params too
    @crew.user = current_user # assigning the user from session / not important here
    if @crew.save
      ......
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating the gender_id in the first place?  You can get back to the gender_id of the Crew within a Meeting with: meeting.crew.gender_id

Comment: updated source, thx, but that does'nt resolve the problem. When the validator is run, record.crew is still Nil

Comment: I more mean: why does Meeting have its own gender_id?  Why not just store it on Crew only?

Comment: Because gender_id can be MALE, FEMALE, NEUTRAL, I crew can have NEUTRAL members (MALE+FEMALE), but some of they meetings can have only MALE members, where others can have for example only FEMALE members. That is more a logical question, still does'nt resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a workaround, in the Crews controller:

```
def create
  @crew = Crew.new(params[:crew])
  if @crew.meetings.to_a.size > 0
    @meeting = @crew.meetings.first
    @meeting.crew = @crew
    @crew.meetings = [] 
    @crew.meetings << @meeting
  end
  @crew.user = current_user
  ....
end
```

I now, it's not pretty, but it works, it can be delegated to a model method, but I want show here a working solution. The question is still open...